# Can I read files in GHCJS?

Tags: haskell, ghcjs

HTML5 introduced a standard file API. Does GHCJS give access to that? Can I use the standard Haskell IO facilities in `System.IO`?

Comment: @bheklilr Nothing, I'm evaluating whether to use GHCJS for GUI programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to implement standard `System.IO` facilities using the HTML5 file api.

Here are some things that are possible with `System.IO`, but aren't possible with the HTML5 File API:

- Writing files
- Reading *arbitrary* files. In fact, there is no way to get *any* identifier for a file, the only way to get access to a file is by letting the user select the file in some way. There is no way to refer to a file by name.
- Any operations on directories

As you can see, the HTML5 file API can pretty much only be used to upload files, and not to implement standard haskell `System.IO` actions. The only thing you could do is provide a way to get a `Handle` by letting the user select a file, and then provide `hRead` for that handle (but that's the only operation you can provide).